# What version of Revit does AutodeskForge support?

Tags: autodesk-forge, revit

When converting the file created by Revit 2014 to SVF, the following error occurred:

> The file was saved in an old version of Revit which we don't support.
>   Please upgrade this project to Revit {0} or later.

I found out that the Revit version is old.
I do not know the range of versions of Revit that AutodeskForge supports.
Does it matter if Revit 2016 or later?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The minimum supported version is Revit 2015. Sorry for not having this information available at the website. It's only shown on https://viewer.autodesk.com, when you click the link called "2D and 3D formats".

Comment: There is a contradiction between the site that you introduced and the format supported by this site (https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/developers_guide/supported-translations/). Is the format list on https://viewer.autodesk.com/ correct? It will be helpful if you let me know if there is something you know.